# Date format similar to NSDateFormatterMediumStyle for Monotouch?

Tags: iphone, ios, mono, xamarin.ios

I am trying to format a date as it appears in iOS calendar application.

The format is the NSDateFormatterMediumStyle and displays a date such as "Nov 27, 2011”.
[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDateFormatterShortStyle)

However such a format is not available in the .NET Framework date formats, so I have to use the NSDateFormatter to format the date.
[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

The problem I have is that in Monotouch I cannot find a method in NSDateFormatter to format the date.
In the Apple examples there is a [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]; method, however it looks that this method is missing in Monotouch or there is an alternative?

Comment: As a general rule MonoTouch does not bind things that have a direct .NET equivalent, i.e. it promotes managed code over native code. In case you can't find a matching .NET type/methods then please open bug reports at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jason's comment makes a great point about using the [Rosetta](http://tirania.org/tmp/rosetta.html). It shows that the `stringFromDate:date` selector is binder inside the `NSDateFormatter` type.

**note:** since a lot of the base (shared between MonoTouch and MonoMac) code is open source you can also find the binding sources on [github](https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/foundation.cs).

From the above I assume you should be able to get the results you're looking for (i.e. iOS, not .NET, culture-aware date/time strings) by doing:

```
var f = new NSDateFormatter ();
f.DateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.Medium;
string result = f.ToString (nsdate);
```

Answer (score 2):

.NET supports [custom date formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).  This should do what you want:

```
myDate.ToString("MMM d, yyy");
```

Comment: This format does not take care of the user prefered date format. Some countries use month-date-year, other day-year-month. The NSDateFormatterMediumStyle takes care of the system settings regarding date formating

Comment: Good point.  According to the MT Rosetta (http://tirania.org/tmp/rosetta.html) stringFromDate is mapped to ToString.  However, as @poupou mentions this might not be an exact mapping.